# Como realizar uma conexão com socket utilizando o Hamachi em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket, vpn

Estou tentando me conectar com `socket` em uma outra rede com o Hamachi. Na criação do servidor, eu estou utilizando o IP local e ao me conectar estou utilizando o IP do Hamachi.

Veja meu código abaixo:

```
# Código do Servidor

address = ("<IP Local>", 51474)

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(address)
server.listen(1)

newSocket, clientInfo = server.accept()
```

---

```
# Código do Cliente

address = ("IP do Hamachi", 51474)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(address)

print("Conectado com sucesso.")
```

O problema é que ao tentar executar o código acima, eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> socket.connect(address)
>
> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Nenhuma conexão pôde ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor ?

Comment: E como configurou o LogMeIn Hamachi? Será que conectou tudo corretamente? Pode detalhar melhor.

Comment: Sim o Hamachi está configurado corretamente e inclusive funciona em outros lugares, como em jogos por exemplo. Também desativei o Firewall já que as vezes ele pode impedir o acesso pelo Hamachi.

Comment: E pelo Telnet conseguiu acessar?

Comment: Não sei o que é isso.

Comment: Faça um teste tentando ouvir o endereço 0.0.0.0 no código do servidor.

Comment: Testei com o endereço `0.0.0.0` e agora ele apresentou um erro diferente: TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Uma tentativa de conexão falhou porque o componente conectado não respondeu corretamente após um período de tempo ou a conexão estabelecida falhou porque o host conectado não respondeu